# Python Lambda Function for List operations

Tags: python

What am I missing here ? If List size is greater than 5, I need last element, else first element.

```
    fn = lambda *d: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]


    print map(fn,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Why are you using lambda here in the first place? The only reason to use it instead of def is when you need to define it in the middle of an expression or don't have a good name to give it. You're defining it out of line, and giving it a name, so this is just a more verbose way of creating the same function with less introspection/reflection information.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use `map` to call a function that works on the whole list rather than each element? Just `print fn([...])`.

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you wanted, probably:

```
fn = lambda d: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]


print fn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
10

print fn([1,2,3])
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your use of map is incorrect. Your example is the equivalent of:

```
print [fn(1), fn(2), fn(3), ...]
```

You have a second problem with your use of `*d` in your lambda. This is special syntax for calling a method with multiple arguments. `d` is now a tuple of all your arguments, so if you call:

```
>>> fn = lambda *d: d
>>> fn([1, 2, 3])
([1, 2, 3],)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
In [124]: n = lambda *d: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]

In [125]: map(n,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
Out[125]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But this is what it is actually doing:

```
In [126]: n = lambda *d: d

In [127]: map(n,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
Out[127]: [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,)]
```

For your purpose, this should be sufficient:

```
In [132]: d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [133]: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]
Out[133]: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `map` here. this [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) link is helpful to you

> As you can see, fn() and gn() do exactly the same and can be used in the
>   same ways. Note that the lambda definition does not include a "return"
>   statement -- it always contains an expression which is returned. Also
>   note that you can put a lambda definition anywhere a function is
>   expected, and you don't have to assign it to a variable at all.

You try this:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
fn = lambda d: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]

print fn(L)
10
```

it also give you same output.

```
def gn(d): return d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]

print gn(L)
10
```

Answer (score 1):

In [1]: print map.**doc**
map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list

Return a list of the results of applying the function to the items of
the argument sequence(s).  If more than one sequence is given, the
function is called with an argument list consisting of the corresponding
item of each sequence, substituting None for missing values when not all
sequences have the same length.  If the function is None, return a list of
the items of the sequence (or a list of tuples if more than one sequence).

this would do what you want:

```
fn = lambda *d: d[-1] if len(d) > 5 else d[0]
map(fn, [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]])
```